# Cannot create Page with test users

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I created some test users for a test app on my Facebook developer account. I would like these test users to be able to create Facebook Pages.  When I try to do that, I get the following error message:

> This content is no longer available The content you requested cannot
>   be displayed at the moment. It may be temporarily unavailable, the
>   link you clicked on may have expired or you may not have permission to
>   view this page.

Is creating Facebook Page something test users can no longer do with the latest FB Graph 2.3 update?

Answer (score 4):

Until Facebook fix this feature on their front end, you can use the API as a workaround:

Begin by creating a new Facebook Test User:

[image]

Give permission to your app to "manage_pages" for this test user (see screenshot).  Get an access token for that user, and use this token to create a page using the API.  If you've never used the Page API, the following Graph API Explorer might help with that (make sure to use the access token for the test user)

Edit: my previous graph API wasn't working when I tried this again, here is another version one of our Q&A team found, that should work.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=POST&path=me%2Faccounts&version=v3.0&name=Bob%20Test%20Page%201&category=756092301147942&about=Bob%20test&picture=https%3A%2F%2Fbowwowinsurance.com.au%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2014%2F12%2Ffrench-bulldog-frenchie-700x700.jpg&cover_photo=%7B%22url%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fbowwowinsurance.com.au%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2014%2F12%2Ffrench-bulldog-frenchie-700x700.jpg%22%7D

Good luck; Facebook's API platforms seem really bugged right now.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem and reported it to Facebook

report [Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1379799389014320)

Comment: Still not fixed as of 5/2 - This is painful for anyone developing a page-based application with permissions that require the review process. You are dead in the water, in terms of submitting an app for approval, until this issue is resolved.

Comment: Any official response from Facebook on that issue?

Comment: Seems to be broken again :-(

Comment: Still broken ... I think they just don't care.